# i keep getting java.lang.NullPointerException in my developer console error report, but i can't reproduce it in the emulator or on my phone

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.surreall.yacht.yatzee.achievementsCheck`(yatzee.java:2031)`
at com.surreall.yacht.yatzee.gameOver(yatzee.java:1929)
at com.surreall.yacht.yatzee$4.onClick(yatzee.java:1250)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

obviously it is happening in the function `achievementsCheck()`, but no matter what i do i can't reproduce the null pointer exception.  what does the "2031" mean in that line? can that tell me anything?

Comment: That's the line number. Line 2031 in yatzee.java.

Comment: Provide code of yatzee.java class with line number..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your question "what does the `"2031"` mean in that line?" It is the line number of the code on which the **NullpointerException** is generating. So look at that line it might be because of an object which is not initialized and has a null reference.

So for example if you have

```
Line 1: Object obj; //Note obj is not initialized here.
Line 2: 
Line 3:       //and you are trying to call
Line 4: 
Line 5: obj.toString()///NullPointer will be generated here
```

You will see a **NullPointerException** generated at line 5

To solve this issue you will have to initialize obj correctly so in this case it will

```
Object obj = new Object();
```

Comment: yes i was able to track down the line of code using this method, thank you.

Comment: I am happy that the answer was useful to you. Thank you